# How to fix “No newline at end of file” warning for lots of files?

Tags: shell, scripting, newline

I have a huge number of source files that are all lacking a newline at the end.

How do I automatically add a newline to the end of each of them?

Some may already have a newline, so it should only be added if necessary.

I'm probably not looking for code, per se, but just something I can run in Terminal to add the necessary newlines (or some kind of programming or development tool).