# While printing a text file making a line break after the last line - confusing due to no space between last line and the $USER

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

For debugging purpose, I was printing the last 2 lines of  a `txt` file from terminal which gives the following. I wanted to check the last line essentially. I got the following.

```
(base) user$ tail -2 ./file.txt
HWI-ST1410:141:C4WJLACXX:4:1201:18182:26815 +   7B  17611409    GTCGTTGTAGTATAGTGGTAAGTATTCCCGCCT
HW(base) user$
```

Even though the last line is just `HW` for a while I thought it was the longer line above since the last line was printed together with `(base) user$` like this: `HW(base) user$`

How can I ensure that there will be a break of line after the last line of the `txt` file I am printing i.e I want the output to be like:

```
(base) user$ tail -2 ./file.txt
    HWI-ST1410:141:C4WJLACXX:4:1201:18182:26815 +   7B  17611409    GTCGTTGTAGTATAGTGGTAAGTATTCCCGCCT
    HW
(base) user$
```

Comment: It looks like the file is missing a newline on the last line; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3261925/3266847)

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my `.bashrc`:

```
__PROMPT_NEWLINE=$'\nV '
__set_missing_newline_fix()
{
       local CURPOS
       echo -en "\E[6n" # ANSI DSR
       read -sdR CURPOS
       CURPOS=${CURPOS#*;}
       if [ $CURPOS -eq 1 ]; then
               __MISSING_NEWLINE_FIX=""
       else
               __MISSING_NEWLINE_FIX="$__PROMPT_NEWLINE"
       fi
}

__set_prompt()
{
       ...
       __set_missing_newline_fix
       ...
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=__set_prompt

PS1="\${__MISSING_NEWLINE_FIX}...rest of the prompt..."
```

The result, in your case, will be:

```
(base) user$ tail -2 ./file.txt
HWI-ST1410:141:C4WJLACXX:4:1201:18182:26815 +   7B  17611409    GTCGTTGTAGTATAGTGGTAAGTATTCCCGCCT
HW
V (base) user$
```

What it does, is query the terminal at the time of generating the prompt (`(base) user$` in your case). If the cursor position is not in the first column, it will start a new line, and prepend `V` to the prompt (hence the value of `__PROMPT_NEWLINE`).

ANSI DSR is [Device Status Report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Terminal_output_sequences):

> CSI 6n | DSR | Device Status Report | Reports the cursor position (CPR) to the application as (as though typed at the keyboard) `ESC[n;mR`, where n is the row and m is the column.)

So by executing `echo -en "\E[6n"` immediately followed by `read -sdR CURPOS` (silently read with the character `R` as delimiter), we get the value of `ESC[n;m`.

`CURPOS=${CURPOS#*;}` removes everything until the semicolon (`;`), which essentially extracts `m`, the column number.

And finally, if the column is not 1, then we know we need to fix up the prompt by prepending `__MISSING_NEWLINE_FIX`.